# C# - Maybe - choice of internal type

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I came across this article: https://www.pluralsight.com/tech-blog/maybe for dealing with nulls in a functional programming manner.
My question is with regard to the internal type being an `IEnumerable<T> value`. From the article:

> There is significance in using an array, instead of a bare value and a
>   flag stating where there is a value. Maybe is actually a special case
>   of list types (such as IEnumerable in .Net).

What is the significance or benefit in doing it this way?

This piece of code is how I would have expected it to be implemented: just using a `T value` and flag:
https://github.com/AndreyTsvetkov/Functional.Maybe/blob/master/Maybe.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Functional.Maybe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The option type; explicitly represents nothing-or-thing nature of a value. 
    /// Supports some of the LINQ operators, such as SelectMany, Where and can be used 
    /// with linq syntax: 
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// // gets sum of the first and last elements, if they are present, orelse «-5»; 
    /// 
    /// Maybe&lt;int&gt; maybeA = list.FirstMaybe();
    /// Maybe&lt;int&gt; maybeB = list.LastMaybe();
    /// int result = (
    ///     from a in maybeA
    ///     from b in maybeB
    ///     select a + b
    /// ).OrElse(-5);
    /// 
    /// // or shorter:
    /// var result = (from a in list.FirstMaybe() from b in list.LastMaybe() select a + b).OrElse(-5);
    /// </example>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    [DataContract]
    public struct Maybe<T> : IEquatable<Maybe<T>>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Nothing value.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Maybe<T> Nothing = new Maybe<T>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The value, stored in the monad. Can be accessed only if is really present, otherwise throws
        /// </summary>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if not value is present</exception>
        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (!HasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("value is not present");
                return _value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The flag of value presence
        /// </summary>
        public bool HasValue { get { return _hasValue; } }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (!HasValue)
            {
                return "<Nothing>";
            }

            return Value.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Automatical flattening of the monad-in-monad
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="doubleMaybe"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(Maybe<Maybe<T>> doubleMaybe)
        {
            return doubleMaybe.HasValue ? doubleMaybe.Value : Nothing;
        }

        internal Maybe(T value)
        {
            Contract.Requires(value != null);

            _value = value;
            _hasValue = true;
        }

        public bool Equals(Maybe<T> other)
        {
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_value, other._value) && _hasValue.Equals(other._hasValue);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            return obj is Maybe<T> && Equals((Maybe<T>) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(_value)*397) ^ _hasValue.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Maybe<T> left, Maybe<T> right)
        {
            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Maybe<T> left, Maybe<T> right)
        {
            return !left.Equals(right);
        }

        private readonly T _value;
        private readonly bool _hasValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that the author is confusing the insight that `Maybe<T>` _is_ indeed a special case of `IEnumerable<T>` with their implementation which is completely unrelated. They use a collection to store the value, to no benefit, and, at the same time, neglect to have `Maybe<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>`, which would be useful and would by no means impact storage details.

Comment: I'd say it's just an implementation detail that has no real impact on the behavior of the object. They're using a single collection to represent the state of the object, instead of two separate ones. Practically just mapping `Maybe.Value => Enumerable.Single()` and `Maybe.HasValue => Enumerable.Any()`. The overhead of using this approach isn't worth it if you asked me.